# How to create this effect using CSS? neumorphism or glassmorphism

Tags: css, sass

Oops my friends, I'm trying to replicate this card but I'm not able to replicate this effect, can you help me with this? I believe it is with box-shadow and linear or radial.
But I can't leave this effect

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to see the exact effect applied here since your screenshot is quite pixelated but this may be what you are looking for: (Run the code snippet)

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #afd275;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.element {
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.22), rgba(255,255,255,0.25));
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
   -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.element-1 {
  background: #afd275;
}

.element-2 {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.22), rgba(255,255,255,0.25));
}

.element-3 {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.22), rgba(255,255,255,0.25));
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="element element-1">Flat</div>
<div class="element element-2">Convex</div>
<div class="element element-3">Concave</div>
</body>
```